# Adding the primary key to the serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to add the id field, which is the primary key to each object, in the list I'm returning

in my models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

in my serializers.py:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

in my views.py:

```
class ListCategoriesView(generics.ListAPIView):
"""
Provides a get method handler.
"""

serializer_class = CategorySerializer


def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    token = request.META.get("HTTP_TOKEN","")
    if not token:

        """ do some action here """

    if not UserAccess.objects.filter(accessToken=token).exists():

        """ do some action here """

    else:
        serialized_categories = []
        all_categories = Category.objects.all()
        for category in all_categories:
          """ I'm filling the object here with the id , and the name """
            serialized_item = CategorySerializer(data={
                    "id": category.id,
                    "name": category.name
                })
            if serialized_item.is_valid():
                serialized_categories.append(serialized_item.data)
        return Response(
            data=serialized_categories,
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

I'm getting the below reponse :

[image]

I want to get this response just with the id field added:

[image]

Comment: Its not a good way how you use the view. The part inside the for loop can be reduced to `serializer = CategorySerializer(all_categories, many=True)`. Or use just the [ListAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just allow the view to do the work.

```
class ListCategoriesView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        token = request.META.get("HTTP_TOKEN","")
        if not token:
            """ do some action here """
        elif not UserAccess.objects.filter(accessToken=token).exists():
            """ do some action here """
        else:
            return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: you're right if I dont have any conditions, but I have to check several conditions before doing that.

Im checking a header parameter if its available in the database if true Im returning this response

Comment: you can still use the built in functionity - and can override get_queryset to filter out results if needed

Comment: I edited the question, if you can check if we can filter and show me how, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: added also line for line, your additions. It could also be done with a permissions class, if you wanted to return a error code for not having the permission to do something